# How to get Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) + Eclipse 3.7.2 + ADT 18 working?

Tags: android, development, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android not building on Eclipse neither IntelliJ on 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124963/android-not-building-on-eclipse-neither-intellij-on-12-04-lts)

As the question already says, on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit environment, after installing Sun JDK 6 successfully with a little bit of trouble, i installed Eclipse 3.7.2 from the software center.

Opened Eclipse, Help> Install New Software. Added the Update Site provided by google for android development. It downloaded and installed and asked to restart as it would for any plugin installation. Did so, restarted Eclipse and it doesn't show anything from ADT. It almost seems like its not even installed, but when i checked the plugins installed in Help>"About Eclipse" section, it shows up.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Is it got anything to do with the Global Menu integration issue where previously MENUPROXY was used to solve it?

Comment: I used openjdk, eclipse from repo, and it works fine for me.  Check the directions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124963/android-not-building-on-eclipse-neither-intellij-on-12-04-lts/125011#125011

Comment: Did you add the Android SDK under Preferences>Android -?-

Comment: @aking1012 can you add your comment as the answer? I Would like to tick it as the correct answer

Comment: @rm-vanda Initially even that did not appear. It was as though adt hadnt been installed at all