# Uninstalling programs/packages

Tags: package-management, configuration, uninstall

I recently installed tools for android development (eclipse ADT ...) and I installed incorrectly and would like to restart from the beginning. I installed a few packages out of order and I am having trouble getting the tools configured. How do I remove everything I just installed, so that I may start all over?

How do I know that all the files are removed?

Comment: Did you use the packagemanager for installation?

Comment: I think I covered that here http://askubuntu.com/questions/124963/android-not-building-on-eclipse-neither-intellij-on-12-04-lts/125011#125011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove any package with many possible ways in Ubuntu.

1.**Software centre** -> In the installed application list you can find all what you have installed and you can remove them from there it self.

2.**Synaptic Package Manager** -> Here also in the search field you can type the application.

3.**Aptitude** -> This is a CLI tool.

4.**apt-get** -> Here by using the following command in terminal you can remove any application/Package

```
sudo apt-get remove <Application_name>
```

one more thing to remove any application completely along with its configurations files you can do the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge <Application_name>
```

Hope that going to help you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not have Synaptic Package Manager run this command from terminal (ctrl + alt + T) as root.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

then search for the specific package from the search box, tick it to mark for complete removal. This will remove the package plus all of its dependencies.

mojo706 :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the apt log, found in `/var/log/apt/history.log`

There you can see a log of the packages you installed through apt / synaptic

If you remember when did you do the wrong installation, just remove the packages listed there as installed in such period of time.