# Does Ubuntu satisfy OS requirements for Android dev by default?

Tags: android, glibc

I'm an aspiring programmer trying to set up an environment for Android development. I know from experience that software requirements need to be fulfilled before I can reasonably expect everything to go without a hitch. I can't seem to figure out the "glibc 2.7 or later" part of it. I have Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit. In Synaptic the closest things I can find are "glibc-doc 2.15" and "eglibc-source 2.15." Is it possible to get glibc 2.7 with Synaptic Package Manager/Ubuntu Software Center or do I need to roll my sleeves up? Or are these version numbers (2.15 and 2.7) not referring to the same thing?

Comment: Search the site for Android development environment.  It IS possible to get it working (first hand knowledge) http://askubuntu.com/questions/124963/android-not-building-on-eclipse-neither-intellij-on-12-04-lts/125011#125011

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't mean to imply that I thought it was impossible. I actually haven't tried it yet. I just wanted to work through the list of system requirements (on which "glibc 2.7+" is first) before I tried to get it working. I'm meticulous in that way for fear of breaking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Ubuntu 12.04 is sufficient for Android dev. The package name for glibc in Ubuntu is [libc6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libc6). You can check libc6 version by `apt-cache show libc6`.

> Package: libc6
>   Priority: required
>   Section: libs
>   Installed-Size: 9125
>   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
>   Original-Maintainer: GNU Libc Maintainers 
>   Architecture: i386
>   Source: eglibc
>   Version: 2.15-0ubuntu10.3
>   Replaces: belocs-locales-bin, libc6-i386
>   Provides: glibc-2.13-1, libc6-i686

I'm running this on Precise. It shows that libc6 provides glibc-2.13 which is greater than 2.7. You don't really need to install an outdated glibc 2.7.

Comment: "2.13 is greater than 2.7" -- That's enough to make my head spin. Wikipedia says the latest version is 2.17. I guess I still don't know where the 2.7 is coming from. I guess I'll take everyone's word for it, though. Thanks.